Не получается собрать нужную информацию с Selenium
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import undetected_chromedriver as uc
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

driver = uc.Chrome()

driver.get('https://2gis.kz/almaty/search/Алматы%2C%20школа')

n = 0

kartochki_list = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='_awwm2v']").find_elements(By.XPATH,"//div[@class='_1kf6gff']")

for i in  kartochki_list :

    n += 1
    status = i.find_element(By.XPATH,"//div[@class='_1idnaau']//span[@class='_oqoid']").text
    
    print(f'{n} {status}')

Просто хочу собрать статусы всех организаций но на всех итерациях выводит статус первой карточки. Помогите пж.
